# C++ code coverage - gitlab runners, cmake, and absolute paths

Tags: c++, cmake, gitlab, code-coverage

When a project is integrated in a gitlab CI pipeline, this pipeline is often broken into several steps :

- compilation
- unit tests
- integration tests

These tests can be executed on a runner pool, with each step potentially on a different server/runner

My issue here is with code coverage.
To my understanding code coverage analysis follows the following steps :

- Compile your project with --coverage : it will generate .gcno files
- Run your tests : it will generate .gcda files
- Run a reporter of your choice, lcov or gcovr, to produce coverage reports for gitlab/sonarqube

When all of this is done in a single job on a single runner, everything works smoothly.
However, when you start to split steps between different jobs, you encounter a path issue.

CMake produces absolute paths in your .gcno files. So when you go to run your tests, the absolute paths being referenced may not exist, and you won't be able to generate a coverage report.

How do you work around this problem ?

I tried using

- manually patching .gcno files with a sed command. Not enough
- making cmake generate relative paths : couldn't find an easy way

Comment: Do you use docker images for your project? With docker you shouldn't have any path issues, because all the project layout: workspace, binary dir, resources dir will be the same. Can you show the example of the conflicting paths? Maybe you just need to download your artifacts in the correct place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Our CI team only provides shell runners so far, this might be an argument to use docker runners. The conflicting path comes from a seemingly random working directory when the runner clones the project : /home/gitlab-runner/somerandomstring/group/project

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody stumbles upon this issue, we finally found a workaround this issue, tested on a small project so far

- Patch the cmake generated makefile to use a relative path for your cpp files : your .gcno files will use relative paths as well

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./build/
  script:
    - PROJECT_DIR=$PWD
    - mkdir build && cd build
    - cmake ../ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=COVERAGE
    # Kludge : Patch absolute paths into relative paths
    - find . -name build.make -exec sed "s|-c $PROJECT_DIR|-c ..|g" -i {} \;
    - make -j8
```

- Override your .gcna files location with GCOV_PREFIX and GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP

```yaml
unit_tests:
  stage: test
  coverage: '/^TOTAL.*\s+(\d+\%)$/'
  artifacts:
    reports:
      coverage_report:
        coverage_format: cobertura
        path: coverage.xml
  script:
    - export GCOV_PREFIX=$PWD
    # Typical shell runner path is /home/runner/builds/<runner_id>/0/<group>/<project>
    - export GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP=7
    - cd build
    - ./tests
    - gcovr -r ../ . --txt --cobertura ../coverage.xml
```